# textview should scroll if it reaches the view in my included layout Android

Tags: android, textview

Hello I have a relative layout with other views and included layout. Following is what I have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="@drawable/ihealthfirst"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/tabsfordiseases" />
</LinearLayout>

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDiseaseDescription"
    style="@style/DescriptionHeader"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/l1"
    android:layout_marginTop="28dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/note16"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<ScrollView
        android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/lvDisease"
        android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDiseaseDescriptionContainer" >

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/tvDiseaseDescriptionContainer"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDiseaseDescription"
    android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

  </ScrollView>


    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvDisease"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvDiseaseDescription"
        android:layout_marginBottom="65dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="15dp" >

    </ListView>

    <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/zooming_controls" />
</LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

FYI, see this: [image]

This is what's happening to my layout. The textview should be below the Disease Description
and when the user clicks on the button tabs above, it should display the listview and other textview. in the included layout you see the zoom controls I have. When the user would zoom in the text, the scrollbars should be visible, not permitting it to go beyond the included layout. and the textview should be below the Disease Description. How can I do this? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this..

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/tvDiseaseDescription"
    android:layout_marginLeft="36dp"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/tvDiseaseDescriptionContainer" >

<TextView
 android:id="@+id/tvDiseaseDescriptionContainer"
 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
 android:layout_height="wrap_content"
 android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" 
 android:layout_below="@+id/tvDiseaseDescription"
 android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|right"
 android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />
```

=======other  views=====

Comment: Hi I tried this but when I got it scrolling, the included layout (the bottom one) is overlapping. How can I prevent this? please respond thanks.

Comment: yes it is below my listview:  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/l2"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:gravity="center_horizontal" >

    <include layout="@layout/zooming_controls" />
</LinearLayout>

Comment: sorry for delay...I was on holiday...but I think now you found the solution..thanx

Answer (score 0):

Just try to add the line `android:layout_below="@+id/tvDiseaseDescription"` in your `Scrollview`.